# Firestore is not retrieving the complete data values

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Image 1 shows the hierarchy of my DB.

I am trying to retrieve the names of the courses [Android, Branding .... ]. The data in italics(Branding, others) gets added by the backend - post commands, and the other data is added typing. While retrieving only the non - italics data gets retrieved as seen in screenshot 2. I can not figure out why this might be happening. Screenshot 2 also shows the query I am using to the same. Please help !!

Thank you.
[image: Firebase Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 2):

> While retrieving only the non - italics data gets retrieved as seen in the screenshot 2

Document IDs shown in italics - means there is not actually a document in its place; however, there are subcollections with documents organized underneath them. Firestore query returns only non-empty documents.

You have two options to go with,

- If you are sure about your document IDs, you could directly access the collection

```js
firestore.collection('users/groups/groupID/courses/others/courses').get()
```

- Using `collectionGroup` queries; but it seems you have many collections with same ID `courses`, so it might retreive all and might not be suitable for you! I recommend you to read [firabase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) for it's limitations

```js
firestore.collectionGroup('courses').get()
```