# Get subcollection of a non existent document using python firebase-admin

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am using python's firebase-admin. I want to fetch the subcollection (and its documents) but the problem is the parent documents of the subcollection do not exist. Even though the subcollections of the non existent documents are still accessible.

Here is the screenshot of the cloud firestore

[image: firestore-screenshot]

Here is the code I tried but it prints nothing:

```
db = firestore.client(app)
message_docs = db.collection('message').get()
for doc in message_docs:
    print(doc.id)
```

Is it possible to fetch subcollections using python in this scenario? I don't know the ID of the documents.

Comment: Do you know the ID of the document whose subcollection you want to access?  Please edit the question to be more clear about what you know ahead of time and what exactly you need to access from your data set.

Comment: I want to fetch the documents inside the subcollection. I don't have the document IDs.

Comment: similar SO ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993832/firestore-is-not-retrieving-the-complete-data-values/65994222

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48177661/10285344 See this answer.

Comment: Alright so basically not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a document ID, it's not possible.  If you want **all** of the documents from **all** of the subcollections of **all** of the documents in "message" (both missing and present), then you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).  Without a document ID, you can't construct a query for a specific subcollection.